# *pointsWithinPolygon* on Trufjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, turfjs

I'm trying to get some point inside multiple polygon using *pointsWithinPolygon* in [turfjs](http://turf.js), but the result is unexpected.

Is there any chance that *pointsWithinPolygon* isn't compatible with *FeatureCollection*?

Here is the example of my usage.

```
let points = {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        106.866995, -6.261513
    ]
}

let filter = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "IdArea": 4
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            106.314674,
                            -6.6348689124
                        ],
                        [
                            107.5781628906,
                            -6.6348689124
                        ],
                        [
                            107.5781628906,
                            -5.9742195859
                        ],
                        [
                            106.314674,
                            -5.9742195859
                        ],
                        [
                            106.314674,
                            -6.6348689124
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

let result = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, filter);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: please describe what the result is and in what way it is unexpected

Comment: Result: geojson with empty feature
Expected: one point that intersect with the polygon, in this case the result supposed to be geojson with one point feature

Comment: See this example: http://turfjs.org/docs#pointsWithinPolygon.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use geoJsons as inputs to turf's pointsWithinPolygons function.

The function takes a turf.points array of points, and a turf.polygon array of polygon vertices.

Based on the variables you established, you would need to call:

```
let result = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(turf.points([points.coordinates]), turf.polygon(filter.features.geometry.coordinates));
```